# C++ Memory Leak new operator

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, memory-leaks, new-operator

I need to identify which objects are destroyed AND if there is any memory leaks on this code.

```
  void myfunc()
  { 
    Photo a(1, 2);
    Photo* pt = new Photo(2, 3);
    throw runtime_error("to test the exception");
  }
```

My answer was

the object is destroyed after the function end
, by automatically calling the destructor of the class Photo.

There is a memory leak.
We did not delete pt that is dynamically allocated with new operator.
So we need to add delete pt;  at the end of function.

Is my anwer is correct?

Comment: Your answer is wrong. This is why smart pointers were invented.

Comment: @chris The question is very oddly worded but I think the answer is right and your comment is wrong.

Comment: @MooingDuck, I was most specifically talking about putting `delete pt;` at the end. AFAIK, that won't execute when an exception is thrown before that line.

Comment: @chris good call, I overlooked that part

Comment: Oh smart pointer... can anybody show the example with the smart pointer?

Comment: @asd213sasdd2254121: `std::unique_ptr<Photo> pt(new Photo(2, 3));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are wrong. try this:

```
void myfunc()
{ 
   Photo a(1, 2);
   Photo* pt = new Photo(2, 3);
   throw runtime_error("to test the exception");
   delete pt;
}
```

compile and run under valgrind. you will get a leak - `delete pt;` is never reached.

Comment: Then should I put delete pt; before the throw line??

Comment: If you must use `delete` here you would need to place it before the throw in order for it to be executed. If you don't need to use `delete` use smart pointers (`std::unique_ptr`). Scope Based Resource Management (SBRM) wants to be your friend.

Comment: no. no. that will not help in the general case. you should use RAII - that is, smart pointers, as chris and Captain Obvlious noted in their comments. if that's impossible, use `try` and `catch (...) { delete pt; throw; }`.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious, I've never heard that specific term, but I do like it better than RAII. It's a shame the first thing that comes up when I search SBRM is The Santa Barbara Rescue Mission.

Comment: Apparently I have a word association problem today...that should read Scope _Bound_ Resource Management. SBRM and RAII are the same thing. Member variables are scoped to the class they are declared in just as local variables are scoped to a function. This is called automatic storage duration since they are automatically created and destroyed. Resources which are allocated and release through `new` and `delete have dynamic storage duration and need to be managed manually.

Comment: @CaptainOblivious: Umm, smart pointers are there so that resources with dynamic storage durations don't need to be managed manually.